# Using Cain and Abel to capture traffic of machine in the same network

Tags: security, networking

I have installed Cain and Able in a machine(A). Machine A is connected to another machine via lan(B). Now I want to analyze all the traffic of machine B. Is this possible by installing Cain and Abel on machine A?
**EDIT**
After truing a bit more - cain and abel is able to sniff packets of the machine B. But the problem is How do I view the packets. It only shows the number of packets captured/sniffed.

Comment: Please avoid duplicate questions on multiple SE sites: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13936/using-cain-and-abel-to-capture-traffic-of-machine-in-the-same-network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ash,

As we discussed in chat while Cain is a great tool for ARP poisoning , Wireshark is far a better tool for analysis. Good news is when you are using Cain to recieve the ARP poisoned packets you can also use Wireshark and sniff the packets at the same time.

Get the binary here http://www.wireshark.org/

Once you have begun poisoning with cain simply select the same interface you are poisoning from in Wireshark and click start capture. This view will be far superior to what you could see when using Cain.

Of note, know there are other ARP cache poisoning programs out there that are more purpose built for this sort of application. One of the best I have found is ettercap. It will also work very well with Wireshark or any other sniffer you choose to employ.

I hope our discussion helped.

dc

Comment: Actually cain and abel is able to sniff packets of the machine B. But the problem is How do I view the packets. It only shows the number of packets captured. you are telling to use wireshark. But will wireshark of system A be able to see the traffic of system B which is in the sam lan.

Comment: you have not still answered my question. How will you use wireshark to capture other machines traffic. As far as I know it can capture only the local machines traffic. To capture other machine's traffic you will have to become MITM. This is done by cain and abel.

Comment: I f you say wireshark is the perfect tool to view packets, then is there a way to see the packets captured using cain and abel in wirshark. If yes, please tell how?

Comment: This is blocked from my office however something tells me your questions will be answered from this link on the cain and abel site.

Comment: okay.. are you atleast sure that there is a way to capture the packets in cain and abel and the view them in wireshark(or fire up wireshark like you said:))

Comment: sorry ..but the link talks about saving the data of wireshark and then using that data in cain and abel to crack the passwords. But  I want the packets in cain and abel to be viewed in wireshark.

Comment: Sorry the site was blocked here the link looked good from google, anyway fireup the cain, start poisoning then sniff the network with Wireshark. It should be that easy..

Comment: One more question dude. In wireshark, I am able to view the ssl traffic. I am able to view the encrypted data over ssl. But I am not able to view the encrypted key during the process of keyexhange. I tried ssl.handshake.encrypted_key. But it does not show any output. I then tried to view the key exchange packet. but even in that packet the encrypted key cannot be found.

Comment: I don't want to decrypt the values. I want to see the encrypted key. However, you said that the actual key is never sent over the wire. I will also look into it and then tell you or post a question like you said.

Comment: I have exceeded my quota of asking question(will be able to ask in another day or two). My friend "Suraj" has asked the question tagged with wireshark, encryption and ssl. The question is titled - "How to see the encrypted key in wireshark, during ssl key exchange?".

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat].